# Magento 2 - Pub/Static files create everything EXCEPT mage folder with important js files (like mixins.js or common.js)

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1, static-content-deploy

I am using Magento 2.4.1 CE. I am not sure what changed, but since about a week when I create my static files the front- and backend break because two folders including important files are missing (e.h. mixins.js require.js) and the javascript files crash.

I have checked all the files and realized that every file and folder is available except the "mage" folder. I use the `bin/magento s:s:d -f`  command.

So whats missing is

> pub/static/frontend/theme/name/de_De/mage/

and

> pub/static/adminhtml/theme/name/de_De/mage/

I have found a workaround by manually uploading the two mage folders from an old stage server into the static theme folders. Then both back- and frontend are fine. This however works only until the next static deployment of course...

I have already checked my file permissions, but since I did not change them, I don't think it has something to do with it.

When I try to open the files by URL as in this example `de_DE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js` I get the following error message:

```
 Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/theme/name/de_DE/mage/requirejs/mixins.js'
<pre> #1 Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource#0000000069ad91c00000000031b30d8d#) called at [pub/static.php:13] 
</pre>
```

Comment: could it be that the original files are no longer exist? did you check the location of it? (lib folder, not pub/static)

Comment: It turns out that this was indeed the case, thanks a lot for the hint! Only the mage folder was all empty and I have no clue why since I would never touch the lib folder. Would you like to make it an official answer?

Comment: No need :D you can post the answer yourself :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimmy pointed out, the original files did no longer exist. Must have been an accident of someone deleting the folder.